# Group by then sum of multiple columns in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame with hundreds of feature columns, like this:

```
Country | ID   | Feature_1 | Feature_2 | Feature_3 |....
US        123       1            5          0
US        456       0            10         1
CA        789       0            6          1
CA        999       0            3          0
...
```

I want to perform a group by on Country, then take the sum per feature, so I should end up with something like this:

```
Country | Feature_1 | Feature_2 | Feature_3 | .... 
US             1          15         1 
CA             0           9         1
```

How can I efficiently compute the aggregate sum function for all of my hundreds of features? I know for one feature, it's like this:

```
df.groupBy("Country").sum("Feature_1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df = Seq(
  ("a", 9, 1),
  ("a", 4, 2),
  ("b", 1, 3),
  ("a", 1, 4),
  ("b", 2, 5)
).toDF("name", "x", "y")

df.groupBy(col("name"))
  .agg(
    sum(col("x")).as("xsum"),
    sum(col("y")).as("ysum")
  )
  .show(false)
```

If you want to make it dynamic:

```
var exprs:List[Column] = List()

for(col <- List[String]("x", "y")){
  exprs :+= expr(s"sum($col) as sum_$col")
}

df.groupBy(col("name"))
  .agg(
    exprs.head, exprs.tail:_*
  )
  .show(false)
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! For the dynamic code snippet, I'm getting an error on the first line (var exprs), is that supposed to be an empty list or a list of all the columns?

Comment: I'm getting this error on that same line: error: not found: type Column

Comment: i'd love to mark your answer as accepted! just trying to make your second dynamic code snippet work

Comment: you have to add the import. "import org.apache.spark.sql.Column"